# How can I form a correct query?

Tags: android, post, request, retrofit

I have next documentation:

> To create an account-access-consent, you'll need to pass an
> access-token identifying your App: simply replace CLIENT_ID and
> CLIENT_SECRET in the curl below to retrieve a valid one:

```
curl -k -X POST \
  https://mandarine.sai.com/token \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&scope=accounts'
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200
status: 200
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
 
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "access_token": "Ci5A6huK2OD0d6...kVwLE9FuHwHGCf6xo5",
    "expires_in": 7200,
    "scope": "accounts"
}
```

So i tried to next in my ApiInterface:

```
@Headers(
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
)
@POST("/token")
suspend fun requestToken(
    @Query("client_ id") clientId: String,
    @Query("client_secret") clientSecret: String
): AccessTokenResponse
```

But I'm not sure that I'm filling in the `data` correctly for my request, namely, it's not clear where I should still place `client_credentials` and `scope`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this request, it was necessary to write the following request:

```
@Headers(
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
)
@POST("/token")
suspend fun requestToken(
    @Query("grant_type") grantType: String,
    @Query("client_id") clientId: String,
    @Query("client_secret") clientSecret: String,
    @Query("scope") scope: String,
): AccessTokenResponse
```